# Craft or Twig filter for MD5 or SHA3 hash creation?

Tags: filter, hash

I've been digging around and haven't found an existing Twig filter for what I'm trying to do. Basically, I'd like a filter that would provide a hash of a phrase.

Pseudo-template code would be something like this:

```
{{ "my phrase here"|hashwithmd5 }}
```

And would generate this in my rendered template:

```
6e6d5618f8ab8a302a236eac07c59300
```

Does something like this exist? Am I going about this in a bad way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sounds like a simple [plugin](https://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) will do the trick for you. You will need to set up your [main plugin class](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up) and a [variable class](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables).

Your variable class will look something like this:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class YourPluginNameVariable
{
    public function makeHash($string)
    {
        $hashed = md5($string);
        return $hashed;
    }
}
```

You can call this in your templates like this:

```
{{craft.yourpluginname.makeHash('my phrase here')}}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's what I thought I might need to do. Just didn't want to reinvent the wheel if I didn't need to. Thank you!

Comment: I wrote one quickly and have posted it to my GitHub page: https://github.com/johnfmorton/Craft-MD5-Twig-Filter-Plugin You use it like {{ "my phrase here" | toMd5 }}

Comment: Nice! Seems a cleaner than using the variable route in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

I needed a hash that only changed if the resource file is modified thus allowing reliable caching.

Usage:
<img src="{{ hash('/images/my_image.jpg') }}"

Can be used for javascript, css or an image resource.

```
// src/Twig/appExtension.php
namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('hash', [$this, 'hash'])
        ];
    }

    // add hash to resource
    public function hash($filename)
    {
        $filepath = getcwd() . $filename;
        $md5 = md5_file($filepath);
        return $filename . "?hash=" . $md5;
    }
}
```